# Set a default value for i18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, internationalization

I'm using i18n for translation in my java script file.
All the translation key-value pair are stored in a JSON file translation.json
It is working fine and i'm able to get the translations in the desire languages.
But when i try to read a key which is not present in translation.json i'm getting blank value which is as expected.
My question is, will it be possible to get the value as "unknown" when i try to read a key which is not present in JSON using data-18n or in other words is it possible to set a default value for data-i18n when it receives blank value?

Here is a example of how i'm using i18n in my HTML code.

```
<label class="form_lbl" data-i18n="translation.password"></label>
```

and my translation.json file looks something like this:

```
{
   translation: {
     password: 'Password'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jQuery.i18n readme](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n/blob/master/README.md), you can set the default text like this:

```
<label class="form_lbl" data-i18n="translation.password">DEFAULT TEXT</label>
```